# How best way can I generate a CRUD UI in a Spring Boot 2 project? Similar to how Django does it

Tags: java, spring

I am a fresh Spring Boot developer coming from a Django background. I like what i see so far but I've been searching for a way to auto-generate CRUD UI from my Entities similar to how Django admin does it out of the box. I'm not averse to solutions that require a little tinkering.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot does not provide you that kind of feature but there are some additional tools that can easily do it for you - the most popular is [jHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/)

Comment: I've had a look at jHipster as it seems to keep coming up as a response to this issue but it comes with a loooooooot of scaffolding. Was hoping for something a bit more minimalistic. Had a look at [Apache Isis](https://github.com/apache/isis) and [OpenXava](https://www.openxava.org/ate/crud-java-framework) but those don't seem to play well with Spring Boot

Comment: @VusumuziKhoza have you tried Vaadin Framework yet ? Vaadin can generate CRUD UI automatically for your beans at runtime check here : https://vaadin.com/directory/component/crud-ui-add-on

Comment: I'll shamelessly plug my project here as well: https://github.com/aileftech/spring-boot-database-admin 
It generates the UI at runtime, it's still in a very early stage so not very solid yet! Looking for feedback.